# Java datastructures/ C++ STL equivalents?

Tags: java

I just started learning java. I already know C++ and python.
In order to learn Java, I am kinda drawing analogies from what I know in C++.
I was an avid user of STL libraries in C++ (vectors, deques, stacks, hashmaps) http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/stl_introduction.html

At the same time, python also have standard dicts, lists etc easily figurable in their docs.

I have been googling lately to find STL equivalent in Java but am unable to find so?
Can someone point me to right resources?

Comment: "Collections" are the rough equivalent of the standard container you know in C++.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_collections_framework

Answer (score 10):

1. std::vector -> j.u.ArrayList
2. std::unordered_map -> j.u.HashMap
3. std::map -> j.u.TreeMap
4. std::set -> j.u.LinkedHashSet
5. std::unordered_set -> j.u.HashSet
6. std::stack -> j.u.ArrayDeque (j.u.Stack is deprecated),
7. std::queue -> use j.u.LinkedList (also take a look on j.u.ArrayBlockingQueue).
8. std::priority_queue -> j.u.PriorityQueue
9. std::span -> no definite analogue
10. std::deque -> j.u.ArrayDeque
11. std::list -> j.u.LinkedList
12. std::forward_list -> no analogue

Important notice: the mentioned associations have similar API but may have different asymptotics of operations and implementation.

Notice: `j.u` means `java.util`.

Comment: Actually map is not LinkedHashMap, LinkedHashMap is a hashmap that we can iterate in insertion order, whereas a map in c++ is basically a BST (red-black) and in java the equivalent would be SortedMap which implements a TreeMap

Comment: These are rough analogues, and I compared them by provided API, not by implementation